# snapcraft crosscompile

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, raspberrypi, cross-compilation, autotools

I am on a x86_64-linux-gnu machine and trying to build a snap from source for arm-linux-gnueabihf (Raspberry Pi3) using autotools.

I manage to build the snap but after I upload to the store it always says that the supported architecture is:

> Supported architectures amd64

My snapcraft.yaml looks like this:

```
name: hellocsnap
version: '1.17'
summary:  Hello World snap written in C 
description: This snap says hello and adds 2 numbers.
grade: stable
confinement: strict
apps:
  hello:
    command: hellocsnap
parts:
  test-hellocsnap:
   plugin: autotools
   configflags: 
       - --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
       - --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
source: source/
```

When running `snapcraft` I get the following error:

```
Priming test-hellocsnap 

Unable to determine library dependencies for b' /home/..../prime/bin/hellocsnap'
```

Does any one know how to pack a snap from source on a amd64 for Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that snapcraft does not yet provide option to crosscompile code for different architectures.

I wanted to do the same thing but could not figure out how to use autotools to do it. Instead I used eclipse to build my project and configured it to build for armhf. Later on I placed executable and everything needed for my app to work to one folder and used `plugin: dump` instead of `plugin: autotools`. You will need to add `architectures: [armhf]` if you are planning to add it to the Ubuntu store. I got the same message like you did but I already tested the code without the snap and I knew that I packaged everything I need so I just ignored it.

Alternatively you could take a look at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) which could help you build it for a variety of environments.

Comment: Did you have to add `--target-arch armhf` to your call to snapcraft?

Answer (score 0):

I did run:
snapcraft build --target-arch=armhf

And it ran all the way through without an error. However it did not create a hello_2.10_armhf.snap package as expected.

snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: hello
version: '2.10'
summary: GNU Hello, the "hello world" snap
description: |
  GNU hello prints a friendly greeting.
grade: devel
confinement: devmode
parts:
  gnu-hello:
    source: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.10.tar.gz
    plugin: autotools
```

Comment: Just run snapcraft --target-arch=armhf, without the "build" keyword. Produces a nice snap package ready to go.